# kivy key error when removing a widget by id

Tags: python, kivy

I added the widget by:

```
current_mouth = Image(
        source=character.current_mouth,
        pos_hint=character.mouth_pos,
        size_hint_y= None,
        height= 500,
        id='mouth_'+str(character.id)
    )
    print('mouth_'+str(character.id))
    self.ids.float.add_widget(current_mouth)
```

Then i try to delete it:

```
self.ids.float.remove_widget(self.ids['mouth_'+str(character.id)])
```

But this throws Key error. What did i do wrong here? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `ids` dictionary is built when a `kv` file/string is loaded. You cannot assign an `id` (at least not one that will appear in `ids`) in python. So nothing added using `add_widget()` will appear in the `ids`.

From the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.html#ids):

> When the kv file is processed, weakrefs to all the widgets tagged with
> ids are added to the root widget’s ids dictionary.

You can just use a reference to that widget when you want to remove it. Without seeing more of your code, I cannot be sure what that would be. But something like:

```
self.ids.float.remove_widget(current_mouth)
```

Comment: i see, thank you. so is there a way to remove a widget added by add_widget()?

Comment: thanks but they are in two separate methods so i can't use current_mouth when removing it. Is there a better way other than making current_mouth global so i could reference it again?

Comment: Use `self.current_mouth = ` when you create it, then remove it with: `self.ids.float.remove_widget(self.current_mouth)`